# Redshift - truncating string when inserting to target

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two tables. Table A is an operational store and table B is the destination table.

Table A DDL:
Column A Varchar(1000)

Table B DDL:
Column B Varchar(250)

So I'm trying to do an insert of truncated column A as so:
Insert into table B (select left(table a.column a, 249)) , but it gives the error

"error:  Value too long for character type"

I have also tried substring to try and truncate the text but to no avail. Please note, that there is also Arabic text in Column A - but it hasn't been an issue in Table A.

Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I doubt that's the full error. It probably says `Value too long for character varying (250)`. Though Redshift isn't really PostgreSQL, so who knows. **Show the full, exact error message** and the exact SQL you are running.

Comment: ERROR: Value too long for character type
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Value too long for character type
  code:      8001
  context:   Value too long for type character varying(250)
  query:     769317
  location:  funcs_string.hpp:390
  process:   query0_44 [pid=12023]
  -----------------------------------------------

Answer (score 5):

To get around the issue of multi-byte characters, you can cast your field to the desired VarChar size using ::VarChar([some length]).  For your example, you would do:

Insert into table B (select table a.column a::VarChar(250))

Comment: this has been bugging me forever!  Thank you, I can only vote once, but I wish it could be a thousand!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each Arabic symbol taking more than 1 byte because RedShift is Unicode DB. The varchar definition is in bytes. So to be on safe side you can divide everything by 4.

Comment: Hi Yuri. Yes this does seem to be the case. I have set it to varchar(140) on the target table and so far, so good. I would upvote you if I had the rep to! Thanks